# Abstraction in SQLAlchemy conditional filtering

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, abstraction, flask-wtforms

I've created models for my database:

```
class Album(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128))
    year = db.Column(db.String(4))
    tracklist = db.relationship('Track', secondary=tracklist,
                                backref=db.backref('albums',
                                lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')

class Track(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128))

class Artist(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    releases = db.relationship('Track', secondary=releases,
                               backref=db.backref('artists',         
                               lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
```

They are many-to-many related Album <--> Track <--> Artist

Next, I have this form:

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    search_by_album = StringField('Album', validators=[Optional()])
    search_by_artist = StringField('Artist', validators=[Optional()])
    search_track = StringField('Track', validators=[Optional()])
    year = StringField('Year', validators=[Optional(), Length(max=4)])
```

My idea is to give the user freedom in filling desired combination of forms (but at least one is required), so I've got this function, which recieves SearchForm().data (an immutable dict 'field_name': 'data'):

```
def construct_query(form):
    query = db.session.query(*[field.label.text for field in form if field.data and field.name != 'csrf_token'])
    if form.search_by_album.data:
        query = query.filter(Album.title == form.search_by_album.data)
    if form.search_by_artist.data:
        query = query.filter(Artist.name == form.search_by_artist.data)
    if form.search_track.data:
        query = query.filter(Track.title == form.search_track.data)
    if form.year.data:
        query = query.filter(Album.year == form.year.data)
    result = query.all()
    return result
```

My question is if there is a more abstract way of adding filters in the function above? If one day I decide to add more columns to my tables (or even create new tables), I will have to add more monstrous ifs to constrcut_query(), which will eventually grow enormous. Or such an abstractions is not a pythonic way because "Explicit is better than implicit"?

PS
I know about forms from models, but I don't think that they are my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be associating the filter-attribute with the fields at some place, e.g. as a class attribute on the form itself:

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):

    search_by_album = StringField('Album', validators=[Optional()])
    search_by_artist = StringField('Artist', validators=[Optional()])
    search_track = StringField('Track', validators=[Optional()])
    year = StringField('Year', validators=[Optional(), Length(max=4)])

    # map form fields to database fields/attributes
    field_to_attr = {search_by_album: Album.title,
                     search_by_artist: Artist.name,
                     search_track: Track.title,
                     year: Album.year}
```

When building the query, you could then build the where clause in a pretty comfortable way:

```
def construct_query(form):
    query = db.session.query(*[field.label.text for field in form if field.data and field.name != 'csrf_token'])

    for field in form:
        if field.data:
            query = query.filter(form.field_to_attr[field] == field.data)

    # or:
    # for field, attr in form.field_to_attr.items():
    #    if field.data:
    #        query = query.filter(attr == field.data)

    result = query.all()
    return result
```

Adding new fields and attributes to filter on would then only translate to the creating the field and its mapping to an attribute.

Comment: That's it, sir! Indeed much simplier and pythonic than what I was trying to do. C# still sitting tight my mind (god forgive me for thinking of interfaces in python)